# A Question on Plancherel decomposition of p-adic groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

Assume $G$ is a $p$-adic group. If $\pi$ is an irreducible quotient of $C_c^\infty(G)$, then there is a surjection $C_c^\infty(G)\twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_G(C_c^\infty(G),\pi)^\star\otimes\pi$.

The Plancherel decomposition says there are G-invariant semi-positive hermitian forms $(\cdot,\cdot)_\pi$ indexed by $\pi$ for almost all $\pi$ on the support of the Plancherel measure such that $(\cdot,\cdot)=\int_{\hat{G}}(\cdot,\cdot)_\pi \, d\mu(\pi)$ and $(\cdot,\cdot)_\pi$ factors through $C_c^\infty(G)\twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_G(C_c^\infty(G), \pi)^\star\otimes\pi$. In this case, $(f_1,f_2)_\pi = \operatorname{tr}(\pi(f_1)\pi(f_2)^\star)$.

I am confused why $\operatorname{tr}(\pi(f_1)\pi(f_2)^\star)$ factor through $C_c^\infty(G)\twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_G(C_c^\infty(G),\pi)^\star \otimes\pi$. Thank you all the time.

Comment: Can you explain the map from $C_c^\infty(G)$ to the tensor product? And how can a bilinear map factor throufg a linear one?

Comment: The map is given by $f \mapsto \sum_i\Phi_i^{\star}\Phi_i(f)$. And for the "factor through", I mean for each component of bilinear map can factor through the quotient of $C_c^{\infty.}$

Comment: What is this sum over? What are the $|phi_i$? Mind that the Plancherel decomposition is not discrete.